# How to get a blur event with Nativescript (IOS)

Tags: ios, nativescript

I need to mimic a web/browser based piece of functionality where a blur event is used to trigger some post entry-field handling.

However using a TextField with Nativescript I only have the "returnPress" event (as far as I can see from the UITextFieldDelegateImpl class source). This event works but is not what I need.

There is some interesting code in there though, especially the textFieldDidEndEditing method:

```
    public textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let owner = this._owner.get();
    if (owner) {
        if (owner.updateTextTrigger === UpdateTextTrigger.focusLost) {
            owner._onPropertyChangedFromNative(TextBase.textProperty, textField.text);
        }

        owner.dismissSoftInput();
    }
}
```

It looks like this should be the place to fire a blur event but maybe there is some other way to accomplish what I need without messing with the framework code.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and found that you could use `Observable.propertyChangeEvent` and the `GestureModule`. The next code snippets showcase the mentioned approach.

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" loaded="loaded">
  <StackLayout id="stack">
  <Label text="Test" textWrap="true" id="label"/>

     <TextField  returnKeyType="done" updateTextTrigger="focusLost"  hint="text" id="textfield" text="{{ textfield }}"  autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" />
     <TextField hint="test2" text="{{  }}" id="textfield2"/>

  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.js

```
var observable_1 = require("data/observable"); 
var gestures_1 = require('ui/gestures'); 
var textFieldEmail;

function loaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var textField = page.getViewById("textfield");
    var stackLayout = page.getViewById("stack");
    var observable = new observable_1.Observable();
    observable.addEventListener(observable_1.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function (pcd) {
        console.log(pcd.eventName.toString() + " " + pcd.propertyName.toString() + " " + pcd.value.toString());
    });
    stackLayout.on(gestures_1.GestureTypes.tap, function (args) {
        console.log("Tap");
        if (page.ios) {
            textField.ios.resignFirstResponder();
        }
        else {
            textField.android.clearFocus();
        }
    });
    page.bindingContext = observable;
}
exports.loaded = loaded;
```

Comment: It took me some time to figure out what you were doing as I am much more used to TS syntax but I get the feeling that this at least gives me a way to know what field is active (or is activated) and gives me a way to code against that. I will give it a try. Not as simple as a blur event but for now I think there is not much better. Thnx